# Which review comment-option do I pick?

Tags: support, reviewing

I just [reviewed this low-quality answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/26914) and agreed it should be deleted.

[image: that's enema the LANGUAGE, thank you.]

I'm kinda new to this whole "reviewing" thing but I understand the basics of what to do and what not to do, so I clicked "Recommend Deletion."

Sweet! More fancy buttons for clicking:

[image: no pr0n in the tabs This Time]

I'm aware PPCG isn't a *"typical"* SE in its Q&A format, and so sometimes things are a little weird, but... which do I choose? It's really, none of the above. (I'm surprised there's no option for "This answer attempts to answer the question but is unrecoverably bad".)

I left the option as "no comment needed", but in edits and *the comment section* and other places SE make it **abundantly** clear that comments are encouranged and looked for when trying to quantify the validity of something, which makes me feel obliged to leave a comment.

It would be good if there were a little free-response box for me to type a valid reason, but there isn't.

What should I do next time?

---

Note that my question of "which option?" is ***not*** specific to the review in question: for almost *no* answer on PPCG would the given options be satisfactory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a comment exists explaining what's wrong and based on that comment it's obvious why the post should be deleted, you should upvote that comment. If no such comment exists, you should consider adding one. You can then vote to delete with "No comment needed" selected.

Comment: Ah, that seems obvious now, thank you.

Comment: @cat No problem. :)